# Another request for more search results with requestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, http-headers, multipartform-data

**Step 1)** I am using following header to send a request to handelsregister.de:
[image]

The page I get back contains a list of company names. The list is limited to 200 results. The limit can be expanded by clicking on a link:
[image]

**Step 2)** When clicking on that link, the browser uses following request to double the results:
[image]

I am stuck when trying to double the results. In Step 2) I have tried to use following code and header. The sessionId is always the same for every request I start.

```js
const HEADERS = { 
  Host: 'www.handelsregister.de',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
  Accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.5',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  Referer: 'https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/mask.do?Typ=e',
  Connection: 'keep-alive',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  cookies: 'language=en; JSESSIONID=230A34728AC6FD3487E88E1A311279A0-n1.tc031n01'
}

function duplicateResult() {
  // I appended ?doppelt to the url, but I don't receive a duplicated result
  const url = 'https://www.handelsregister.de/rp_web/search.do?doppelt';
  
  const formData = HEADERS;

  request.get(url, formData, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error); // no error
    console.log(body); // the search page of handelsregister.de, with no query started
  });
}
```

How can I double the results?